# Render partial with collection and display counter for each object with Pagy Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to display the index of each record in a collection when it's rendered in my rails app.

For example:
Name, 1
Name, 2
Name, 3.
....

I use the built-in hidden index to accomplish this today, but after adding pagination with the Pagy gem the index restarts every time I go to a new page. So if I display 20 records per page, the first index on page 2 should be 21, but it currently displays 1.

**Heres' my code:**

teams_controller.rb

```
def index
if params[:query]
  @pagy, @teams = pagy(Team.includes(:stadium).global_search(params[:query]))
else
  @pagy, @teams = pagy(Team.order_by_score)
end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: "teams/card", collection: @teams, as: 'team' %>
```

in my partial.html.erb

```
<%= team_counter +1   %>
```

---

Any idea on how I can display the index of each record without it having to restart on each page?

Anything that could help me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Rails has a built-in counter method,  "#{partial_name}_counter"

Referenced here:
https://coderwall.com/p/t0no0g/render-partial-with-collection-has-hidden-index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@pagy.offset` returns the offset of the current page which you can pass to `with_index` to calculate the correct index of a record.

```
<% @teams.each.with_index(@pagy.offset) do |team, index| %>
  <%= render partial: "teams/card", team: team, index: index %>
<% end %>
```

and show the index in your `teams/card` partial like this:

```
<%= index %>
```

When you want your index to start from `1` instead of `0` just change `with_index(@pagy.offset)` to `with_index(@pagy.offset + 1)` in the above example.